# Tracking changes in DOM is slow to get triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, userscripts

I have a very simple piece of code that i did for twitch chat that allows me to see the image posted by someone directly in the chat. I'm not doing extreme verification i just want to transform any image link into a `<img>` tag.

```
(function() {
'use strict';
$('.tw-flex-grow-1').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    $(".link-fragment").each(function(){
        if (($(this).text().indexOf(".jpg") > 0 ) || (($(this).text().indexOf(".png") > 0 )) || (($(this).text().indexOf(".gif") > 0 ))|| (($(this).text().indexOf(".jpeg") > 0 ))){
            $(this).html("<img src='" + $(this).text() + "' width='200px'/>");
        }
    });
});
```

})();

I found out that DomSubTreemodified can track changes in a div. But my problem is that this thing is slow. It will do its job but it's really slow and i don't know why exactly. And i know that with a lot of messages it can be slow because of the ".Each" but this i will solve later, this is slow  with one message only.

Is that the wrong approach? How can get that domsubtreemodified trigger faster?

## EDIT

Following the suggestion in the comments:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
var targetNode = document.getElementsByClassName('tw-flex-grow-1')[0];

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        alert("test");
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            $(".link-fragment").each(function(){
                if (($(this).text().indexOf(".jpg") > 0 ) || (($(this).text().indexOf(".png") > 0 )) || (($(this).text().indexOf(".gif") > 0 ))|| (($(this).text().indexOf(".jpeg") > 0 ))){
                    $(this).html("<img src='" + $(this).text() + "' width='200px'/>");
                }
            });
        }
        else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

})();
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @SLaks Can you check the adapted code? Test gets triggerred sometimes but not childlist

Comment: it actually gets triggered only at the begining with this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big issue is probably that for each mutation, you are going through each `.link-fragment`, even if you've already handled it.  What you want to do is only look at the contents of the newly added node (and it's children) and run your code on that.  Try this:

```js
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var targetNode = document.getElementById('target');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: true };

function alterNode(node) {
    if (node.textContent.indexOf('gif') !== -1) {
        const image = document.createElement('img');
        image.setAttribute('src', node.textContent);
        image.setAttribute('width', 200);
        image.setAttribute('height', 200);
        node.appendChild(image);
    }
}
// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(node) {
            if (node.classList.contains('link-fragment')) {
                alterNode(node);               
            }
            node.querySelectorAll('.link-fragment').forEach(function(node) {
                alterNode(node);
            })
        });
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

document.getElementById('adder').addEventListener('click', function() {
     let imageLink = document.createElement('div');
     imageLink.classList.add('link-fragment');
     imageLink.textContent = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/l2R0aKwejYr8ycKAg/giphy.gif';
     document.getElementById('target').appendChild(imageLink);
});
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>

<button id="adder">Add Image Link</button>
```

Comment: I do something like this : 
    var targetNode = document.getElementsByClassName('chat-room')[0]; to get my targetNode. But this always returns no nodes. If i inspect the dom i can see it's there. And my userscript is running on dom ready. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Well i didn't bother i put up the observer really high now and it sees the changes, i don't mind the performance. Thanks man.